# Tensorflow Saver() not saving as .ckpt file

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to run a simple program to save a Tensorflow session to the disk as "spikes.cpkt". Although in the interactive program, the system output showed that I have successfully created that file, I can not find that file in the file system.

The version of Tensorflow I used is 0.11rc using Python 2. The operating system is Ubuntu 16.04. The program was written and run in Jupiter notebook.

The following is the source code of saving session:

```
# Import TensorFlow and enable interactive sessions
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Let's say we have a series data like this
raw_data = [1., 2., 8., -1., 0., 5.5, 6., 13.]
# Define a boolean vector called `spikes` to locate a sudden spike in raw data
spikes = tf.Variable([False] * len(raw_data), name='spikes')
# Don't forget to initialize the variable
spikes.initializer.run()

# The saver op will enable saving and restoring variables.
# If no dictionary is passed into the constructor, then the saver operators of all variables in the current program.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Loop through the data and update the spike variable when there is a significant increase
for i in range(1, len(raw_data)):
    if raw_data[i] - raw_data[i-1] > 5:
        spikes_val = spikes.eval()
        spikes_val[i] = True
        # Update the value of spikes by using the `tf.assign` function
        updater = tf.assign(spikes, spikes_val)
        # Don't forget to actually evaluate the updater, otherwise spikes will not be updated
        updater.eval()

# Save the variable to the disk
save_path = saver.save(sess, "spikes.ckpt")

# Print out where the relative file path of the saved variables
print("spikes data saved in file: %s" % save_path)

# Remember to close the session after it will no longer be used
sess.close()
```

The output of the system is in Figure (1):
[image]

The files created in the File System is shown in Figure (2):
[image]

There is no file named "spikes.ckpt" in the disk.

Comment: Looks like `spikes.ckpt` is the prefix used by the saver, rather than actual filename

Comment: The saving format name is different with some versions of TensorFlow (it will be solved if you upgrade to 0.11 but reappear on 0.12rc). It adds the .data-00000-of-00001 at the end of the .checkpoint file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TensorFlow recently introduced a new checkpoint format (Saver V2) which saves the checkpoint as a set of files with a common prefix. To create a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) that uses the old format, you can [create it](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.__init__) as follows:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V1)
```

Comment: Not working now:
WARNING:tensorflow:*******************************************************
WARNING:tensorflow:TensorFlow's V1 checkpoint format has been deprecated.
WARNING:tensorflow:Consider switching to the more efficient V2 format:
WARNING:tensorflow:   `tf.train.Saver(write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V2)`
WARNING:tensorflow:now on by default.
WARNING:tensorflow:*******************************************************

Comment: @ZijunLost You can ignore that warning in the current version of TensorFlow. However, support for the V1 format may be removed in a later version of TensorFlow (2.0 or later).

Comment: you're right. It saves to 2 files instead of three as in version 2.0. It also seems that most of the code we are using are indifferent to the versions? For example the `inspect_ckpt.py` seems to be compatible with version 2.  My follow-up question is: is there anything we need to pay attention with dealing with different version of save files? Also, what's more in version 2?

Comment: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'write_version' when using 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the name of the variable in [tf.trai.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables)

```
saver = tf.train.Saver([spikes])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I am reading the book Machine Learning with Tensorflow, in the forums you can find also the solution which is to make the path relative

```
save_path = saver.save(sess, "./spikes.ckpt")
```

forum post here https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/41796.page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute path instead of relative. In my case, it solved the issue. Which is a bit strange, because such a mature library as TensorFlow should support relative paths.